# Transparent nav-bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following issue:

- I use a navbar with background-color
- I want to delete the background-color and make it transparent
- I deleted the background and applied `position:absolute` to it

**Information:** The image blow shows the design after `position:absolute`. The attached sample code is showing the original design before I applied changes to make it transparent.

**Problem:** After I applied `position:absolute` to navbar the items moved from right to left.

**Goal:** Just to make the goal clear: I want same navbar just with transparent background.

[image: Images shows the change after position:abosulte]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  clear: both;
}

.spalten-6 {
  width: 49.99992%;
}

.spalten-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.spalten-6,
.spalten-12 {
  float: left;
}

.img-box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-box {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
}

#video-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px
}

#video-container {
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video#bgVid {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url('http://ewallpaperhub.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/nature-wallpaper-3.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

video#bgVid.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}

nav {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  font-size: 13px;
}

nav ul li a.logo {
  background-color: black;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: ;
}

li {
  float: right;
}

li:first-child {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a img {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.abstand-top {
  margin-top: 10px;
}


}
nav ul li a img {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
.abstand-top {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/" class="logo">BOOMYEAH</a></li>
    <li class="abstand-top">
      <a href="#"><img src="Images/icon-facebook.svg" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li class="abstand-top">
      <a href="#"><img src="Images/icon-instagram.svg" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">WORK   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  |</a></li>
    <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">CREW</a></li>
    <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="video-container">
  <video id="bgVid" loop class="fillWidth" autoplay>
<source src=http://bigcom.com/assets/2014/08/iChooseB.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>
</div>
```

Hope we will find a solution.

Comment: How is your problem related to navbar being transparent? The title `Issue with transparent Navbar` gives an impression that your problem is related to bg color. Plz update title to suite your problem.

Comment: When i run this code, the links that are, Contact, Crew, About and Work, are all the way to the right of the screen, do you want them to stay at right or float to left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You didn't set the position of the `nav` to absolute
2. You set the background color to black, so it will not be transaper.
3. You need to set the `z-index` to make sure it has higher `z-index` so the user can click on the items in the menu.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
        
        .row {
            clear: both;
        }
        
        .spalten-6 {
            width: 49.99992%;
        }

        .spalten-12 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .spalten-6,  .spalten-12 
        { float:left;} 
   
        .img-box img {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .img-box {
            border-left: 2px solid white;
            border-top: 2px solid white;
        }
        

#video-container {
    position: relative;
    height:300px
}
#video-container {
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}
video#bgVid {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    background: url('http://ewallpaperhub.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/nature-wallpaper-3.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
video#bgVid.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
   position:relative
}

nav {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    font-size: 13px;
}

nav ul li a.logo {
    background-color: black;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: ;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li:first-child {
    float: left;
}
        
       nav ul li a img {
           width: 16px;
           height: 16px;
           float: right;
           margin-left: -20px;
}

        .logo {
            font-size: 20px;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        }
        
        .abstand-top {
            margin-top: 10px;
            
        }

    
        }
        
      
       nav ul li a img {
           width: 16px;
           height: 16px;
           float: right;
           margin-left: -20px;
}

        .logo {
            font-size: 20px;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        }
        
        .abstand-top {
            margin-top: 10px;
            
        }
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://google.com/" class="logo">BOOMYEAH</a></li>
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="#"><img src="Images/icon-facebook.svg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="#"><img src="Images/icon-instagram.svg" alt=""></a></li> 
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">WORK   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  |</a></li>
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">CREW</a></li>
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">CONTACT</a></li>
       
    </ul>
</nav>


<div id="video-container">
<video id="bgVid" loop class="fillWidth" autoplay>
<source src=http://bigcom.com/assets/2014/08/iChooseB.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `background-color: rgba()` property for the nav bar. `rgba()` is a function which takes 4 parameters, first three are the color values of RED, GREEN and BLUE, and the 4th parameter is transparency of the background, which can vary from 0 to 1. So, after adding it your code should look like:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
        
        .row {
            clear: both;
        }
        
        .spalten-6 {
            width: 49.99992%;
        }

        .spalten-12 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .spalten-6,  .spalten-12 
        { float:left;} 
   
        .img-box img {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .img-box {
            border-left: 2px solid white;
            border-top: 2px solid white;
        }
        

#video-container {
    position: relative;
    height:300px
}
#video-container {
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}
video#bgVid {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    background: url('http://ewallpaperhub.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/nature-wallpaper-3.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
}
video#bgVid.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
   position:relative
}

nav {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 10;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    font-size: 13px;
}

nav ul li a.logo {
    background-color: black;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: ;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li:first-child {
    float: left;
}
        
       nav ul li a img {
           width: 16px;
           height: 16px;
           float: right;
           margin-left: -20px;
}

        .logo {
            font-size: 20px;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        }
        
        .abstand-top {
            margin-top: 10px;
            
        }

    
        }
        
      
       nav ul li a img {
           width: 16px;
           height: 16px;
           float: right;
           margin-left: -20px;
}

        .logo {
            font-size: 20px;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        }
        
        .abstand-top {
            margin-top: 10px;
            
        }
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://google.com/" class="logo">BOOMYEAH</a></li>
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="#"><img src="Images/icon-facebook.svg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="#"><img src="Images/icon-instagram.svg" alt=""></a></li> 
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">WORK   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  |</a></li>
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">CREW</a></li>
        <li class="abstand-top"><a href="http://google.com/">CONTACT</a></li>
       
    </ul>
</nav>


<div id="video-container">
<video id="bgVid" loop class="fillWidth" autoplay>
<source src=http://bigcom.com/assets/2014/08/iChooseB.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video> 
</div>
```

You can change the 4th value in the rgba() function as you want, i set it to 0.8.